# Set From And To Address in Email Activity in CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Hi How to set To and From Address in Email Activity using C# Silverlight.

Please Suggest.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This example is taken from CRM 2011 SDK. Here the sender is a user, and the reciveing end of the email is a contact.

As you can see, to and from(the same goes for cc and bcc) is an array of ActivityParty. Where the partyid is a entityreference.

```
var fromParty = new ActivityParty
{
    PartyId = new EntityReference(SystemUser.EntityLogicalName, _userId)
};

var toParty = new ActivityParty
{
    PartyId = new EntityReference(Contact.EntityLogicalName, _contactId)
};

var email = new Email
{
    To = new ActivityParty[] { toParty },
    From = new ActivityParty[] { fromParty }
};
```